# Prove that there exists a finite subcollection of a set having measure greater than set's measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$.Let $E$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $E\subset \bigcup\limits_{k}J_k$, where $\{J_k\}$ is a countable collection of open intervals. Prove there exists a ﬁnite subcollection $\{J_{k_l}\}$ of $\{J_k\}$ consisting of disjoint intervals such that 
$$\mu(E\cap(\bigcup\limits_{l}J_{k_l}))\ge (\mu (E))/2.$$

Could you please help me with this? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Looks something like Simple Vitali Lemma (however that is not strong enough)